# How to apply check in ansible to verify wether environment path already exists or not?

Tags: windows, ansible

I have a yml file using ansible commands. Inside the file i am appending a service location to the existing environment path as follows:

```
 -name: retreiving the path
  raw: $ENV:PATH
  register: path_out

- name: adding the services to the environment path
  raw: SETX /M PATH "$ENV:PATH;{{item.service_path}}" 
  with_items:
    "{{ services }}"
```

So, what happens is everytime when script is executed it will append the service path to the existing environment path even if the same service path was previously added, this creates appending of the same service path again and again. Hence what i want is to have a check to verify if service_path was already added it won't apend it again at the end. I tried following but did not helped:

```
- name: adding the services to the environment path
  raw: SETX /M PATH "$ENV:PATH;{{item.service_location}}" 
  with_items:
    "{{ services }}"
  when : ansible_env.PATH;{{item.service_location}}.exists is not defined
```

Its not working at all please help how to have check? platform is windows on which i am working

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify the PATH variable itself. Instead modify the PATH in /etc/environment or set the PATH per Task if it is only used there.

A good example can be found here: https://coderwall.com/p/ynvi0q/updating-path-with-ansible-system-wide

```
- name: add {{extra_path}} to path
  lineinfile: >
  dest=/etc/environment
  state=present
  backrefs=yes
  regexp='PATH=(["]*)((?!.*?{{extra_path}}).*?)(["]*)$'
  line="PATH=\1\2:{{extra_path}}\3"
```